# How to bind formControl to an object with object's id? PrimeNG Dropdown

Tags: angular, dropdown, primeng, form-control, formgroups

I'm using angular and primeNG Dropdown.

**Code First**

```typescript
myForm = this.fb.group({
  id: [null],
  name: [''],
  otherId: [null]
});

options = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: 'option A'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: 'option B'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: 'option C'
  },
];
```

```html
<div [formGroup]="myForm">

  <!-- id -->
  <div class="id-field">
    <input type="text" formControlName="id">
  </div>

  <!-- name -->
  <div class="name-field">
    <input type="text" formControlName="name">
  </div>

  <!-- otherId , This part of code is not correct-->
  <div class="otherId-field">
    <p-dropdown [options]="options" optionLabel="name" formControlName="otherId">
    </p-dropdown>
  </div>

</div>
```

As you can see from the code, I'm binding `otherId` to an option(id and name) with it's `id`.
When I select 'option A', `otherId` should be set as `1`.

**BUT** my current practice bind `otherId` to the whole object

```json
{
  id: number;
  name: string;
}
```

That is incorrect.

So any solution to achieve what I want?

Comment: Is it a real problem? You can call `this.otherId.id` if you just want the id, isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below approach

- Create a holder property `otherSelected`
- Watch the change in the dropdown using `(ngModelChange)`
- Update value of the form using `setValue`

see below code and [demo on Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qqpb1h)

```html
<div [formGroup]="myForm">
    <div class="id-field"><input type="text" formControlName="id"></div>
    <div class="name-field"><input type="text" formControlName="name"></div>
    <div class="otherId-field">
        <p-dropdown [(ngModel)]='otherSelected' (ngModelChange)='myForm.get("otherId").setValue(otherSelected.id)' dataKey='id' [options]="options"
                optionLabel="name" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}">
        </p-dropdown>
    </div>

    </div>
    <pre>{{ myForm.value | json }}</pre> {{ otherSelected | json }}
```

```typescript
  name = "Angular " + VERSION.major;
  otherSelected: { id: number | null } = { id: null };
  myForm = this.fb.group({
    id: [null],
    name: [""],
    otherId: [null]
  });

  options = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "option A"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "option B"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "option C"
    }
  ];
```